# Is it possible to set up a farm starting with processed foods?

Tags: agriculture

Given a bare but not sterile environment and the sorts of supplies one would have access to in a well-stocked cafeteria or a bad grocery store, is it possible to start growing food? Assume frozen, canned and otherwise processed food is available but fresh fruits and vegetables are not. Phrased another way: What are the minimum requirements to be able to cultivate food?

I realise this question is relatively broad, but I hope it's okay to ask here - I'm asking this for a story I'm trying to write. I have very little knowledge about farming, except for a vague impression that you can grow things in coffee grounds and that you can make prison wine using bread and fruit juice.

Comment: this is better suited to worldbuilding or AG than here.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have another source of seeds, or are you hoping to get all the seeds to jump-start agriculture from processed food in a grocery store?

If the latter... a lot of our processing kills seeds while sterilizing food. Often we remove the seeds in the first place. For instance, I rarely see bell-pepper seeds in frozen sliced bell pepper, or tomato seeds in sauce. There are seeds in frozen okra, but okra is a hot-climate plant, I don't know if its seeds survive freezing. There might be whole flax and sesame seeds in granola that could still sprout.

I think you should put a damp paper towel somewhere warm and  test things as you find them in the grocery.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be entirely possible to grow a viable source of fruits, vegitables, and grain products.  Soley from you’re grocery listed of processed frozen and canned foods.

Frozen fruits, vegitables, and meats under go a process called *flash freezing*[1](http://m.wisegeek.org/what-is-flash-freezing.htm). Flash freezing has the ability to lock in the vast majority of the produces natural or [food fortified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_fortification?wprov=sfti1) nutritional content. Making these particular items great candidates for [composting](https://eartheasy.com/grow_compost.html).

Now say one allowed those canned processed fortified foods or non. To vermicompost over time to create a nutrient rich, well balanced soil. Then planted crops accordingly. I believe that one could cultivate goods that would thrive rather nicely in the biological make up of your produce soils.

- [eartheasy.com guide to compost](https://eartheasy.com/grow_compost.html)
- [wisegeeks.org definition of flash freezing](http://m.wisegeek.org/what-is-flash-freezing.htm)
- [wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_fortification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_fortification?wprov=sfti1)